# Google Charts Stacked bar formatting and spacing between data

Tags: charts, google-visualization

[image: Did not get proper spacing between data]

I Used this parameter to create chart image

```
    $params['cht']= 'bvs';//Chart Type
    $params['chd'] = "t:";
    $params['chd'].=$finaldata;//
    $params['chm']= 'N,FF0000,-1,,12|N,000000,0,,14,,c|N,000000,1,,14,,c|N,000000,2,,14,,c';
    $params['chs'] = $this->getWidth().'x'.$this->getHeight();// chart size
    $params['chco'] = '4d89f9,C6D9FD,FF0000';//series color
    $params['chbh'] = '80,20';//bar width and space
    $params['chds'] = 'a';//$min_amount.','.$max_amount;//scaling for min and max amount
    $params['chxt'] ='x';//visible axis
    $params['chxr'] ='0,'.$min_value.','.$max_value;
    $params['chg'] ='10,20';//Grid lines background
```

I am creating Stacked bar chart using google Visualization api.
I want to show the data in clear and proper spacing ,Stuck from 2 days .Thank you for help.

Comment: I don't know how to help you. The API you're using is pretty bare-bones and customizable. I agree that the chart isn't pretty, but for the data and values you're talking about, short of doing the filtering yourself, I don't see how Google charts can be expected to remove labels you've requested if they'd overlap. I'd filter the data on your end.

Comment: I hope this comment comes off as more constructive than mean, because I intend for this to be constructive.  The code you have here is very difficult to read, and I've never seen google chart API code written like this.  The properties of the API's objects are obfuscated to help protect google's intellectual property (and save bandwidth), but they have left the methods in the clear so we can work with them.  You can either give the chart an object initializer or use `setOption('option','value')` and it would be much easier to read and find your bugs.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't help but make a second comment, this time on design.  The purpose of a chart is to show the relationships between data, not necessarily to give exact values for that data.  I think your best solution here would be to add value labels on the vertical axis, and not inside the chart area.  If your users need exact values, add a table from the same data (if in print) or use the tooltips to provide more detail.